# How to format time zone offset in lubridate

Tags: r, lubridate

I want to format the date in ISO 8601 format using lubridate. At the moment the code I have parses the date almost the way I want. The only thing I want to change is to have a colon in the time zone offset. My code at the moment:

```
dateTime <- str_match(fileName, dateTimeRegex)[2] %>% ymd_hms() %>% strftime(format = "%y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z", tz = "UTC")
```

Sample output:
"19-09-26T10:45:00+0000"
Expected output:
"19-09-26T10:45:00+00:00"

Is there a simple way to do it, without parsing this manually? %z creates 0000, but I need a colon there

Comment: Your snippet would be reproducible if you replaced `str_match(fileName, dateTimeRegex)[2]` (2 undefined variables!) with an actual date.

Comment: FYI the colon is optional in ISO 8601 so your current output is already a valid ISO 8601 datetime.

Comment: dateTime <- str_match("xxxx_time=201909261045_201909261100.csv", ".*_time=([0-9]{12})_[0-9]{12}")[2] %>% ymd_hms() %>% strftime(format = "%y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z", tz = "UTC")

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) (emphasis mine):

> The UTC offset is the difference in hours and minutes from Coordinated Universal Time (UTC, or GMT) for a particular place and date. It is generally shown in the format **±[hh]:[mm], ±[hh][mm], or ±[hh]**. So if the time being described is one hour ahead of UTC (such as the time in Berlin during the winter), the UTC offset would be **"+01:00", "+0100", or simply "+01"**.

`HH:MM` is just one way to format time offsets, the others being `HHMM` and `HH`, so your output conforms to ISO 8601.

Comment: I know that my current output conforms to the standard, but the other tools I use expect a colon and I don't have influence over that

Answer (score 0):

We can use regex to achieve your desired output. Using `sub`

```
x <- "19-09-26T10:45:00+0000"

sub("(.*\\+)(\\d{2})(\\d{2})", "\\1\\2:\\3", x)
#[1] "19-09-26T10:45:00+00:00"
```

Comment: the point is not to hack the system, but use built-in solutions. Though this is a good workaround